# Get number of players in a scene (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

do you know how can I get the number of players in a specific scene? I'm using Unity Photon's PUN 2, so, almost anything of PUN 1 won't work.
Thanks.

Comment: What code did you use in PUN 1?

Comment: @JeanLuc I haven't used PUN 1 before, I'm a begginer starting with PUN 2

Answer (score 1):

The [PhotonNetwork](https://doc-api.photonengine.com/en/pun/v2/class_photon_1_1_pun_1_1_photon_network.html) class in the Photon.Pun namespace has a static property CurrentRoom where you can get the number of player in a room.

```
using Photon.Pun;

public static class MultiplayerHelper
{
    public static int GetPlayerCount() 
    {
        if (PhotonNetwork.CurrentRoom != null)
        {
            return PhotonNetwork.CurrentRoom.PlayerCount;
        }
        return 0;
    }   
}
```